# How to pick an object in BGE and release it while using NLA actions

Tags: game-engine, armature

I am trying to a pick an object and release it, in BGE. 
I am attempting to use the actions setup in the NLA.

While I can successfully pick and release the object (via Dynamic Parent addon) for rendering purposes, I cannot do the same for BGE as the plugin will not work when using BGE.

Here is what I am trying to achieve (Please ignore auto loop)

[image]

Here is my setup :

[image]

As of now, only the arm (parented to armature) rotates upon pressing SPACEBAR. This is because the cube only contains the animation curve for the parent influence.

How can I achieve the above animation in BGE ?

Regards,

pixelhaze

Comment: Have you looked at the [parent actuator](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/logic/actuators/types/parent.html)?

Comment: @sambler   I have come across the Parent Actuator but I am a bit lost on how to use it. If I use it, I need to set the parent in the initial few frames of the animation and then clear it in the last few frames. Any pointers to where I can find such information will be appreciated.

Comment: You use one to set the parent and one to clear it. You just need to figure a way to trigger the event, maybe [send a message](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/logic/actuators/types/message.html)?